# RuntimeError when i try to integrate pythonBB

Tags: django, python-2.7

I try to integrate djangobb in my project. I find and follow the step of this guide [[How to integrate djangobb in an existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474341/how-to-integrate-djangobb-in-an-existing-project/33745420]) but i have a RuntimeError: RuntimeError: Model class djangobb_forum.models.Category doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
Please help me.

here my settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'blog', #my app
  'account', #my app
  'django_summernote',
  'tinymce',
  'django.contrib.sites',
# SITE_ID = 1
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'giz.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ],
    },
},
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'giz.wsgi.application'
# Database
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'XXX',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',

}
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':          'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
LOGIN_URL =  '/account/connexion/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE= True
```

Answer (score 0):

i install pybb very easy and complete forum
https://pybbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you forgot to add 'djangobb_forum' to INSTALLLED_APPS.